# Setting Page Title with useraccounts:flow-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts, flow-router

I'm just beginning to really dive into Meteor and start some personal projects but I've stumbled across something that I haven't yet found an answer for. I'm trying to set the title of my pages that are used for logging in, signing up, etc. Is there a solution for this? I don't see anywhere in the docs where I can add an option in these configuration statements.

This is my `routes.jsx` file:

```
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute("changePwd");
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute("forgotPwd");
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute("resetPwd");
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute("signIn");
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute("signUp");
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute("verifyEmail");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pull this off with:

```
FlowRouter.triggers.enter([function(){
  document.title = FlowRouter.current().path;
]);
```

This would set the page title = the route path for all routes. If you want route-specific titles then you can add triggers on each route individually. [(docs)](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/triggers)

Comment: This works and I've tried adapting it so that `document.title = FlowRouter.current().name;` but it keeps coming back with `undefined`. I've also updated `AccountsTemplates.configureRoute("signIn");` to `AccountsTemplates.configureRoute("signIn", {
  name: 'Sign In'
});`

Comment: I got it working now. `name` is a child of `route` so the code I used is `FlowRouter.triggers.enter([function() {
  document.title = FlowRouter.current().route.name;
}]);`